# Spring Cloud: Service Registration for JavaEE based microservices

Tags: jakarta-ee, spring-cloud

I'm new to microservices architecture and I'm trying to setup all the microservices, api gateway and service registration by using Spring Cloud.

Some of our developers are writing their services (and hopefully future microservices) with JavaEE.

Is it possible for them to register with Spring Cloud made service registration somehow without using Spring Cloud (and Spring)? I would assume this is done through REST, but I couldn't find any good samples about it on the internet.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could register your services using the REST API provided by Eureka.

https://github.com/Netflix/eureka/wiki/Eureka-REST-operations

There is a little difference between Netflix Eureka and Spring Cloud Eureka. The Spring Cloud service doesn't have '/v2' in the URI path.

So you should consider the URIs provided on Eureka wiki, just erase the 'v2' on path.

Example:

Eureka valid URI to register a new application:

> POST on /eureka/v2/apps/appID

Spring Cloud Services:

> POST on /eureka/apps/appID

The drawback of registering an API manually is that you have to handle exceptions very carefully. Your application shoud un-register when its turned off or something wrong happened and the JVM is almost crashing.

Besides that, I recommend you to test the behavior of your Eureka Server when something goes wrong and the application failed to unregister. Find the ideal values for configuring Eureka heartbeats timeout to your environment.

Comment: Thank you! This is what I was looking for.

Comment: You could also use the eureka library on its own without using spring-cloud

Comment: @spencergibb is there any reason for using it instead of the spring eureka impl?